# elasticsearch - can you give weight to newer documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

If we have 10,000 documents with the same score, but we limit the search to 1,000, is there a way to give more weight to newer documents so the newer 1,000 show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the documents have the same score then the most straightforward way to go is just sorting by creation date:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html

Example with _score as first criteria, and date for tiebreakers:

```
GET /my-index-000001/_search
{
  "sort" : [
    "_score",
    { "post_date" : {"order" : "desc"} },
  ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

If you want to add score on top the query score you can use a distance query on the creation date field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-distance-feature-query.html

```
PUT /items
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "creation_date": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
PUT /items/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "name" : "chocolate",
  "production_date": "2018-02-01",
  "location": [-71.34, 41.12]
}

PUT /items/_doc/2?refresh
{
  "name" : "chocolate",
  "creation_date": "2018-01-01"
}


PUT /items/_doc/3?refresh
{
  "name" : "chocolate",
  "creation_date": "2017-12-01"
}
```

```
GET /items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "chocolate"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "distance_feature": {
          "field": "creation_date",
          "pivot": "7d",
          "origin": "now"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`origin` will define the starting point from where you want to give more weight to the documents which are close, in the example the closest to "now" the document is, the weight it will have.

`pivot` distance of the origin the document will receive half of the score.

Comment: thanks, for option 1, sorting by creation date, i think it will sort the subset of 1,000, rather than sort the 10,000 and return the first 1,000 (now sorted by newest), right?

Comment: That query will sort the 10,000 and return the newest 1000

Comment: i love the simplicity of sort, but i want to do a 2 pass sort, pass 1 is score, pass 2 is date (for tie breakers where the score is equal), is that a possibility? I'm trying to avoid a production reindex if I can help it to implement the second solution.

Comment: Sure, you can specify an array of sorting options, being the first one score, and the second one date for the tiebreakers.

Comment: that is precisely what i need, would you please help with an example? disregard i will try this from the first link you sent

Comment: Sure, I will add it to the answer for visibility